# JSON Payload in Matlab webwrite

Tags: json, matlab, rest, http

I am trying to send the following POST request with Matlab [webwrite](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webwrite.html):

```
POST https://url.to.com/hello/world

HEADERS {"API_KEY": "abc123"}

JSON PAYLOAD

{
"return_type": "hello",
"entities": ["ent1"],
"events": ["legal"],
"fields": [],
"filters": {},
"start_date": "2015-01-01 00:00:00",
"end_date": "2016-01-01 00:00:00",
"format": "csv",
"compressed": false
}
```

In Matlab, I tried the following:

```
API_KEY                 = 'abc123';
url                     = 'https://url.to.com/hello/world';

options                 = weboptions(...
    'MediaType', 'application/json', ...
    'HeaderFields', {...
    'API_KEY', API_KEY; ...
    'Content-Type' 'application/json'});

payload.('return_type') = 'hello';
payload.('entities')    = ['ent1'];
payload.('events')      = ['legal'];
payload.('fields')      = [];
payload.('filters')     = {};
payload.('start_date')  = '2015-01-01 00:00:00';
payload.('end_date')    = '2016-01-01 00:00:00';
payload.('format')      = 'csv';
payload.('compressed')  = 'false';

response = webwrite(url, payload, options);
```

However, this returns the error:

> The server returned the status 400 with message "Bad Request" in
>   response to the request to URL

I tried the request above with **Postman** and it worked. I have also verified that my Matlab headers are properly setup. So it must be my Matlab setup for the JSON payload part. What is wrong there?

---

Update 1:

I noticed that when you run `jsonencode(payload)` that it does not return the desired format. Moreover, the `"[ .. ]"` gets dropped out. I think that the problem starts there as then the request becomes indeed invalid. So we need a way to incorporate the brackets where necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on another forum. The problem was indeed the double brackets. We need to set it as follows:

```
payload.('entities')    = {{'ent1'}};
```

Read more here: https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/217716-how-to-pass-single-element-json-arrays-using-webwrite